# sub div margin top

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="sub">sub</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #565656;
}

.sub {
    background: red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Why does the margin of sub div move wrap relatively to body and not itself relatively to wrap? (probably the dummiest question ever, but I dont get >< )
http://jsfiddle.net/QJug3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to to wondrous world of collapsing margins:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Basically it comes down to this:
If you have two adjacent vertical margins then just one of them is used and the other is ignored. The browser assumes that you intended to have a 1 margin instead of what you would normally expect: 2 margins adding to each other.

The easiest (but not so elegant) way to achieve what you want is to give your `wrap` div a `padding-top` of `1px` so that the margins are no longer adjacent.

```
.wrap {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #565656;
 padding-top: 1px; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: that's why I prefer using paddings as much as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure whether avoiding the problem is the best solution but certainly it's one that is easy to implement and within reach. I do hope that some day in the future this collapsing margin "feature" will be removed. :)

Comment: @SakerONE perhaps giving `wrap` a `height` of `99px` would compensate for the `1px` difference created with the `padding-top`, it depends a little on what you are trying to achieve. :)

Answer (score 2):

Bazzz explained the reason, to achieve what you want (as I understand you)

http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/jHqry

```
.wrap {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #565656;
  position:relative;
}

.sub {
    background: red;
    top: 100px;
  position:relative;
}
```